# Plotting Networkx graph in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, networkx

I recently started using networkx library in python to generate and visualize graph plots. I started with a simple code (comprising of 4 nodes) as shown

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1 ,2) , (2 ,3) , (1 ,3) , (1 ,4) ])
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

When I run the code for two consecutive times, the outputs for same code is as shown in the images (the orientation of the plot is random)

[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

Is it possible to generate the output of the plots with the same/fixed orientation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per default a spring layout is used to draw the graph. This can have a new orientation each time it is drawn.

There are also other layouts available.

[image]

Using e.g. `nx.draw_circular` or `nx.draw_spectral` will give you always the same layout.

You may also define the positions of the nodes using a dictionary, which maps nodenumber to a position.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1 ,2) , (2 ,3) , (1 ,3) , (1 ,4) ])
pos = { 1: (20, 30), 2: (40, 30), 3: (30, 10),4: (0, 40)} 

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Hard coding positions method is quite helpful.